# python как добавить таймер в программу

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, таймер

Добрый день. Есть программа написанная на python3 с графическим интерфейсом PyQt5. В ней много разных модулей и функций. И пока что всё выполняется в одном потоке, т.е. без субпроцессов и мультипроцессинга. В программе есть запускающий модуль:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Base.start_base()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Ui_Form()
    Ui_Form.user_pass(form)
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

и потом, уже в самой программе есть (насколько я понимаю) кусок (модуль def retranslateUi(self, Form): ), где программа крутится по кругу и ожидает нажания клавиш в граф.интерфейсе:

```
        self.Begin.clicked.connect(self.choice)
        self.Clr_mes.clicked.connect(self.clear)
        self.radio_print_user_base.clicked.connect(self.print_userbase)
        self.Foto_Rate.clicked.connect(self.download_fotorating)
        self.Fotorate_folder_btn.clicked.connect(self.fotorate_folder)
```

Мне так кажется, что она тут крутится, как на самом деле она выхватывает эти нажатия - мне неизвестно.

**Собственно, вопрос:** как добавить в програму таймер, который будет следить за временем, и, скажем, каждые 10 минут будет запускать один из модулей программы (иммитировать нажатие клавиши в граф.интерфейсе, которая запускает нужный модуль)? Уточню: прикрутить клавишу, запустить модуль, иммитировать нажатие - я могу. Я не понимаю, как запустить таймер и куда его вписать, который будет работать ОДНОВРЕМЕННО с программой, вне зависимости, чем она в данный момент занимается и что там нажато.

P.S. Пробовал баловаться с модулем multiprocessing, помещая разбивку на процессы под `if __name__ == '__main__':` , но одновременности не получилось, процессы все равно выполнялись по очереди, и один из них надолго зависал (например, прорисовка интерфейса просто зависала и было белое пустое окно), ожидая, пока закончит работу другой. Возможно, просто криво делал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам не нужно проводить сложную вычислительную работу, то хватит самого простецкого [потока](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html):

```
import threading
import time


def my_timer(print_interval):
    data = threading.local()
    data.counter = 1
    while True:
        time.sleep(print_interval)
        print("I am alive %d times!" % data.counter, threading.current_thread().name)
        data.counter += 1

t = threading.Thread(target=my_timer, name="My time thread", args=(5, ), daemon=True)
t.start()
```

Поток прост и завершит свою работу вместе с приложением. Если вы планируете "много считать" внутри, то гольные питоновские потоки не годятся и выигрыша не получится. Единственно заслуживающим внимания может быть только параметр [`daemon`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon). По умолчанию приложение прежде чем завершиться ожидает завершения всех своих дочерних потоков. Если поток был объявлен демоном, то приложение не ждет его завершения. Т.е. без этого параметра приложение будет ждать закрытия вечно (как послать потоку сигнал закрытия - отдельная тема). Демоны удобны тем, что вам вообще не нужно беспокоиться об их закрытии - они работают вместе с приложением постоянно.

Еще может быть интересна функция `sleep` - она приостанавливает работу текущего потока (не всех, не главного, а только текущего), что позволит потоку, управляющему отрисовкой интерфейса заниматься своими делами и никого не ждать.

Однако, есть иной подход, который можно осуществить средствами самого Qt, без плясок с потоками. Под капотом можно почитать про [сигналы и события](https://pythonworld.ru/gui/pyqt5-eventssignals.html), здесь я приведу код для конкретного решения проблемы автора:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QGridLayout, QSizePolicy, QApplication


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.my_counter = 1

        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.label = QLabel("QLabel", self)
        self.label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: pink; font-size: 50pt;}")

        self.button = QPushButton("Test", self)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.local_button_handler)

        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button, 0, 1)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

    def local_button_handler(self):
        self.label.setText("Qlabel" + " %d tick" % self.my_counter)
        self.my_counter += 1


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Window()

timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(win.local_button_handler)
timer.start(1000)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Код создаст простенькое окно, на нем кнопку и надпись. Надпись меняется как с помощью нажатия на кнопку, так и по таймеру.

Comment: вот строка под if name = main: t = threading.Thread(target=Ui_Form.my_timer, name="My time thread", args=(form, 60, ), daemon=True), вот строка под print в my_timer: self.download_fotorating(). В результате я получаю вывод принта, и потом QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread. Знаете, как это исправить?

Comment: на всякий случай - не знаю, кто вам налепил минусов - это не я.

Comment: @UserNew, обновил ответ с конкретным решением конкретной проблемы. Не могу дать подробных комментариев, так как не шарю в Qt, но вроде делает, что нужно: по таймеру должен обновляться интерфейс - он обновляется и ничего не провисает.

Comment: Спасибо. Это оно! Теперь (с QTimer) все отлично работает.

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам пример:

```
import time
import threading as th

def target(form):
    while True:
        print(form) #нажмите кнопку тут
        time.sleep(10)

form = 1 #некая кнопка
t = th.Thread(target=target, args=(form,), daemon=True)
t.start()
#сохраните куда-то переменную t
#del t если вам надо убить поток
```

Можно использывать multiprocessing, но во первых он дает больше нагрузку на систему, а во 2 с ним сложнее управляться

Comment: А в чем проблема моего сообщения?

Comment: Добрый день и спасибо за ваше время. Проблема та же, что и выше была - QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread. Похоже, что в программе с интерфейсом PyQt нужно использовать таймер из Qt (QTimer). На остальные он ругается, т.к. они в других потоках. Я подозреваю, что это можно решить, но довольно сложными методами и костылями. (Если вы насчет минуса - то его ставил не я. Возможно, это был кто-то, кто знает насчет этой несовместимости обычных threads и Qt.)