# Параллельное выполнение процесса в Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Есть программа, где ведется работа с данными сайта. 
Через main() выбираешь нужную функцию и получаешь необходимые данные с сайта, но чтобы работа с этим сайтом велась непрерывно, нужно каждые 7 минут отсылать запрос на выход в онлайн.

Примерный код следующий:

```
def getUsersCount():
  ...

def getOtherInfo():
  ...

def toOnline():
  While True:
     #действия, для выхода в онлайн
     time.sleep(420)

def main():
   While True:
     action = input("Выберите действие: \n"
     "1. Инфа о пользователях\n"
     "2. Что-то еще\n"
     "3. Выйти в онлайн \n"

     if action == "1":
        getUserCount()
     elif action == "2":
        getOtherInfo()
     elif action == "3":
        toOnline()
```

Получается, таким образом если будет выбрана 3 функция, нужно чтобы она отправляла каждые 7 минут запрос, но при этом оставалась возможность выбирать другие функции из программы, а не приостанавливалась работа

Погуглив понял, что нужно использовать multiprocessing, но у самого пока что реализовать не получилось, приложение все равно остается в заморозке, сидит в цикле и ждет 7 минут, не давая доступа к выбору остальных функций

Comment: не обязательно несколько процессов, возможно заменить на несколько программ, unix way. Основная программа только периодически читает новые данные из "базы данных", например из текстового файла. Вторая программа запущена постоянно, но ее задача авторизация на сайте, получение данных и запись в общую базу. Так же можно запускать по крону.

Comment: по таймеру, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639389/python-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83