# Выполнение метода каждую секунду

Tags: python, таймер

Есть метод, который хотелось бы выполнять каждую секунду. Не подскажите как сделать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/639397/227016

Comment: @diraria Спасибо.